# Linked list. Can't change borrowed value

Tags: rust

I am on my way of learning Rust. In practical purpose I decided to make my own linked list collection. But I faced with some problems soon. I tried but can't find any way to fix this problem. Can I do this using this type of structure for linked list? The main problem I faced is implementation of deleting function.This function should delete element from the list with replacing address of the current node with address of the next node. But I can't change the value because it was borrowed already.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum AlmostList {
    Cons(i32, Box<AlmostList>),
    Nil,
}
```

The base of linked list is enumeration.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct List {
    length: u32,
    data: AlmostList,
}
```

But I want the instance of list knows its own length. Because of it I decided to use structure to store the length of the list in it.

```rust
use crate::AlmostList::{Cons, Nil};  

//Implementetion of functions
impl List {

    fn new() -> List {
    
        List{ length: 0_u32, data: AlmostList::Nil }
    }

    fn append(&mut self, elem: i32) {
 
        let mut alist  = &mut self.data;

        loop {
            match alist {
                Cons(_, ref mut ptr) => alist = ptr,
                Nil => {  
                    let node = Cons(elem, Box::new(Nil));
                    self.length += 1;
                    *alist = node;
                    break;
                },
            }           
        }         
    }

    fn show(&self) {
     
        let mut alist = &self.data;
        
        if let Nil = alist {
            panic!("List is empty");
        }
        
        loop {
            match alist {
                Cons(value, ptr) => { 
                                   print!("{} ", value);
                                   alist = &*ptr; 
                },
            
                Nil => break,
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Everything was fine until I started to write function of deleting elements.This function should delete element from the list with replacing address of the current node with address of the next node.

```rust
   fn delete(&mut self, number: i32) -> Option<i32> {
        
        let mut alist = &mut self.data;
        
        let result = loop {
                match alist {
                    Cons(value, ptr) => {
                        if *value != number {
                            alist = ptr;
                        }
                        
                        self.length -= 1;
                        *alist = *ptr.clone();
                        break Some(number);
                        
                    },
                    
                    Nil => break None,    
                }
            };
        
        result   
    
    }
    
}
```

Got this error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `*alist` because it is borrowed
  --> main.rs:79:25
   |
73 |                     Cons(value, ptr) => {
   |                                 --- borrow of `*alist` occurs here
...
79 |                         *alist = *ptr.clone();
   |                         ^^^^^^
   |                         |
   |                         assignment to borrowed `*alist` occurs here
   |                         borrow later used here
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*ptr` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> main.rs:79:35
   |
75 |                             alist = ptr;
   |                                     --- mutable borrow occurs here
...
79 |                         *alist = *ptr.clone();
   |                         ------    ^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
   |                         |
   |                         mutable borrow later used here
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
Some errors have detailed explanations: E0502, E0506.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
```

Can I solve this problem somehow?

Comment: If you're interested in implementing linked lists in Rust, please read through [this guide](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Comment: Thank you. I already found this guide)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can solve this problem. I fixed it in that way:

```rust
    pub fn delete(&mut self, number: i32) -> Option<i32> {
        let mut alist = &mut self.data;

        let result = loop {
            match alist {
                AlmostList::Cons(value, ref mut ptr) => {
                    if *value != number {
                        alist = ptr;
                    } else {
                        break Some(ptr);
                    }
                }
                AlmostList::Nil => break None,
            }
        };
        
        if let Some(ptr) = result {
            *ptr = Box::new(AlmostList::Nil);
            Some(number)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
```

At least the code above was compiled successfully. Full rust playground example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5bd28014bdec30e5c2e851827f15dad5

Additional hints:

- write better namings. Examples: `AlmostLeast` -> `ListNode` (or just `Node`), `Nil` -> `None`, `Cons` -> `Some`. I have feeling that you have experience with Lisp in the past :)
- format your code with `cargo fmt` and check with `cargo clippy`
- any data structure implementations should not panic. Use `Result` type

Update:
Code above is wrong. I've implemented it using recursion: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ea6dbd3a627a59014df823be29e296b2

Comment: Thank you, man, for you attantion to my problem. Your variant compiles but function just truncates list instead deleting element from it. https://onlinegdb.com/QSKgUhZIl

Comment: And your are absolutly right - I'am Lisp'er :)

Comment: @greenrich On the topic of better namings, personally I might even suggest redefining the original enums like `struct AlmostList { value: i32, next: Option<Box<AlmostList>> };` and `struct List { length: u32, data: Option<AlmostList> };`, but the larger issue is you should read the excellent guide from @user4815162342, or better yet use `std::collections::LinkedList`. Or even better yet, IMHO you should just avoid linked lists since *in practice* they are usually MUCH slower than arrays!

Comment: I understand my problem. I can't implement deleting funtion because of Rust's link restriction. I can't mutate the value was borowed something. My variant of deleting function is circlical: i try mutate value which  points on itself. But I want to know are there some methods in Rust to over this problem.

Comment: Hi, I returned with great news. I've implemented deletion BUT with recursion. This code is not excellent and but at least it works: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ea6dbd3a627a59014df823be29e296b2

Comment: Great news. I will explore your solution immidietly. I'am excited.
Gratitude for your job in a lisp style) https://ideone.com/fork/kRSBNP